# Azure IOT Central - REST API - This API cannot be called for the application Error

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk, azure-iot-central

I am trying explore on Azure IOT Central rest apis.
[IOT Central REST Ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iotcentral/)

But when i try to invoke any api, it throws below error,

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "InvalidRequest",
    "message": "This API cannot be called for the application seciotcentral.azureiotcentral.com. If you contact support, please include the following information. Request ID: 8yb2u4iz, Time: Mon, 24 Feb 2020 12:53:21 GMT.",
    "requestId": "8yb2u4iz",
    "time": "Mon, 24 Feb 2020 12:53:21 GMT"
   }
}
```

[image: API]

I tried with different API endpoint, but am getting same  error,
'https://seciotcentral.azureiotcentral.com/api/preview/devices'

I created API token from administrator page in IOT Central,
It is not authorization related issue since i got 400 bad request error.

Please help me to fix it.

Comment: Please include the entire request, what was the URL that you used. What were the headers (did you include the API token?)
Are you using a legacy Central app or the new Preview Central app?

Comment: modified with additional info

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your IoTC App has been a legacy application, see the following screen snippet, where *rk2018iotcentral* is a legacy app.
[image]

when I called your *demoiotcentral* application, the *Unauthenticated* error showup:

[image]

Did you recently changed it?

Comment: Hi, It is not demoiotcentral, name was wrong, it is seciotsectral. I just edited. Please check.

Comment: you mean to say IOT central application i created is old one which does nto support API? will it work if i create new IOT central application and try?

Comment: Is your *seciotcentral* application allows to use a Plug and Play device templates? The REST APIs will work only for that IoTC applications, in other words, they can not be created from *Application template =  Custom application (legacy)*